# ScrollTop function wont work in Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I have a function that I call on the onclick event of a button.

```
function ScrollToEditor() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#ckeditor_editor").offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button id="btnScrollToBottom" class="button right" onclick="ScrollToEditor();" type="button">Scroll</button>
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox and IE11. However, it does nothing in Edge. There are no console errors and the I have made sure that the function is definitely being called.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this issue as well, the only thing that worked for me was the following function:

```
function ScrollToEditor() {
   document.getElementById('ckeditor_editor').scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **pageYOffset** instead of scrollTop

Note: pageYOffset is not supported supported below IE 9

Answer (score 1):

I may be late but I had the same problem. I found the solution in the following code:

```
 function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; //Zero is the pixels from the top of the screen
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

This worked fine for me. I had the problem with Edge. I hope this will be useful for someone with the same problem.